# preg_split() and implode() newbie help please (trying to do tags right)

Tags: php, tags, implode, preg-split

I am using some ready-made code and it was using implode & explode functions to assign tags to photos, tags users typed in.
It was not doing it right though, as if you tried a two word tag, it was splitting it.
So I replaced the explode function with a preg_split function with a regex I found, but even though testing the function & regex on http://php.fnlist.com/regexp/preg_split shows that it splits the tags correctly, in my application it totally ignores any two-word tags.

I am trying to get, from input like "crime, love, mystery    ,crime drama,romance"
nicely formatted tags: "crime,love,mystery,crime drama,romance" and I get instead:
"crime, love, mystery,romance"

I am giving the code I have below.
Please help!!

```
   <?php
class PhotoTagsController extends AppController {
var $name = 'PhotoTags';

var $uses = array('PhotoTag', 'Photo');

function edit($id = null)
{
 $this->authorize();

  if(!($photo = $this->Photo->findById($id)))
  {
    $this->flash('error', ucfirst(i18n::translate('photo not found')));
    $this->redirect('/');
  }
  else
  {
    $this->authorize($photo['Photo']['user_id']);

    $this->set('photo', $photo);

    if(empty($this->data))
    {
      $photo['Photo']['tags'] = array();
      foreach($photo['PhotoTag'] as $tag)
        $photo['Photo']['tags'][] = $tag['tag'];
      $photo['Photo']['tags'] = implode(',', $photo['Photo']['tags']);

      $this->data = $photo;
    }
    else
    { 

    // foreach(explode(',', $this->data['Photo']['tags']) as $tag)


   foreach(preg_split("/[s]*[,][ s]*/", $this->data['Photo']['tags']) as $tag)

      {
        $tag = strtolower(rtrim($tag));  //trims whitespace at end of tag
        if(!empty($tag))
        {
          $found = false;

          for($i = 0; $i < count($photo['PhotoTag']); $i++)
          {
            if(isset($photo['PhotoTag'][$i]) && $photo['PhotoTag'][$i]['tag'] == $tag)
            {
              $found = true;
              unset($photo['PhotoTag'][$i]);
              break;
            }
          }

          if(!$found)
          {
            $this->PhotoTag->create();
            $this->PhotoTag->save(array('PhotoTag' => array('photo_id' => $photo['Photo']['id'], 'tag' => $tag)));
          }
        }
      }

      foreach($photo['PhotoTag'] as $tag)
        $this->PhotoTag->delete($tag['id']);

      $this->flash('valid', ucfirst(i18n::translate('tags changed')));
      $this->redirect('/photos/show/' . $photo['User']['username'] . '/' . $photo['Photo']['id']);
    }
  }
}

function ajax_edit($id = null) {
 $this->authorize();

 if(!($photo = $this->Photo->findById($id)))
 {
   die();
 }
 else
 {
   $this->authorize($photo['Photo']['user_id']);

 // foreach(explode(',', $this->params['form']['value']) as $tag)

foreach(preg_split("/[s]*[,][ s]*/", $this->params['form']['value']) as $tag)

   {
     $tag = strtolower(rtrim($tag));
     if(!empty($tag))
     {
       $found = false;

       for($i = 0; $i < count($photo['PhotoTag']); $i++)
       {
         if(isset($photo['PhotoTag'][$i]) && $photo['PhotoTag'][$i]['tag'] == $tag)
         {
           $found = true;
           unset($photo['PhotoTag'][$i]);
           break;
         }
       }

       if(!$found)
       {
         $this->PhotoTag->create();
         $this->PhotoTag->save(array('PhotoTag' => array('photo_id' => $photo['Photo']['id'], 'tag' => $tag)));
       }
     }
   }

   foreach($photo['PhotoTag'] as $tag)
     $this->PhotoTag->delete($tag['id']);

    echo $this->params['form']['value'];

   die();
 }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is all the code needed to understand your problem? Please only include relevant code.

Comment: Most of this code sample is irrelevant - can you edit out the "fluff" and show only the keyword handling portions that are causing trouble?

Comment: Your regex, `[s]*[,][ s]*` is matching 0 or more letter `s`, followed by a comma, followed by 0 or more [space or letter s]s. `\s` means "space character". The slash is important. And the `[]`s aren't needed around single characters. They represent a character set. Perhaps you should brush up on regexes?

Comment: Hi guys. Many thanks.

They key code is:
foreach(preg_split("/[s]*[,][ s]*/", $this->data['Photo']['tags']) as $tag) 
and 
foreach(preg_split("/[s]*[,][ s]*/", $this->params['form']['value']) as $tag)

I thought I'd give the whole context, wasn't sure how much would help. 
I do not actually know regexes, I am trying to piece together things I found online and the regex I tried was supposedly used for the exact purpose I want. Also, testing it with an online tool, the results were correct.

Comment: Don't know why it does not work.

What regex would you suggest for splitting correctly tags (leaving two or more word tags in one piece)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `preg_split` regex to:

```
/(\s+)?,(\s+)?/
```

Or...

```
/\s*,\s*/
```

Comment: You could use * ... However, I tend to try to avoid using * for lack of greedy management! :p

Comment: Huh? If you want it ungreedy you do `\s*?`. By default it is greedy and will consume as many spaces as it can.

Comment: Tried both suggestions, did not work unfortunately.
I want to allow two or more word tags (not to split those in separate tags). 
How shall I do it?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to over complicate things. If you want to split by comma's, just use the more simple explode() function. You can then use trim() to strip off the white space.

```
$parts = explode(',', $input_string);
foreach ($parts as $value) {
   $results[] = trim($value);
}
```

Comment: There was a similar explode in the script I commented out...it did not work.
My key objective is to allow for two or more word tags (not to split those in separate tags).
Any thoughts?

Comment: Then use a combination of strtolower() and array_unique() as well.